# How do I center a CSS based Drop Down Menu?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center a drop down list, extending the grey rectangle across the screen while keeping the text in the direct center of the screen. There should only be three items at this time. These items are Home, Assignments and Projects.

Here's the html

```
<HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jamcgraw.iweb.bsu.edu/assignments/stylesheet.css" />
    <title>McGraw</title>
</head>
<div align="center">
<body>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Assignments</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
               </li>                      
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a   href="http://jamcgraw.iweb.bsu.edu/projects/project1/project1.zip" target="_blank">
                    Project 1</a>
                </li>                       
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <br />   
    <h2>Some of my favorite websites include:<ul>
        <a href="http://facebook.com/">Facebook</a> </br>
        <a href="http://reddit.com/">Reddit</a> </br>
        <a href="http://twitch.tv/">Twitch.tv</a> </br>
        <a href="http://youtube.com/">Youtube</a> </br>
        <a href="http://noxxic.com/">Noxxic</a>
        </ul>
    </h2>    
</body>
</html>
```

and the .css for the DDM

```
/*Begin Theme Style Code*/
/*Begin Regular Code*/
* {
margin: 0px;
}
/*End Regular Code*/
/*Begin Menu code*/
#menu-container ul,
#menu-container li,
#menu-container span,
#menu-container a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
#menu-container {
/* EDITED : ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE */  
text-align:center;


height: 49px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
background: #141414;

  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
}
 #menu-container:after,
 #menu-container ul:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 }
 #menu-container a {
 background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  #menu-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  }
  #menu-container > ul {
  }
  #menu-container > ul > li {
  /*EDITED : CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE*/
  float: left;
  }
  #menu-container > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  }
#menu-container > ul > li:first-child > a {
border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-container > ul > li:last-child > a {
border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0px 0 0;
 }
 #menu-container > ul > li.active > a {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
 background: #070707;      background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#menu-container > ul > li:hover > a {
background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c), color-stop(100%, #070707));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
 }
#menu-container .has-sub {
z-index: 1;
}
#menu-container .has-sub:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li {
*margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li a {
background: #0fa1e0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #6fc7ec;
filter: none;
font-size: 11px;
display: block;
line-height: 120%;
padding: 10px;
}
#menu-container .has-sub ul li:hover a {
background: #0c7fb0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: 0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
background: #0c7fb0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #6db2d0;
}
#menu-container .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
background: #095c80;
}
#menu-container {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #888;
}
/*End Menu Code*/
/*Begin Button Code*/
button.button {
border: 0 none;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
height: 34px;
line-height: 22px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 1px;
padding: 4px 11px 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #00CCFF;
font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

button.button:hover {
background-color:#24459A
}
/*End Button Code*/
/*Begin Table Logo Code*/
table.header {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: none;
}

table.header td {
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
padding: -1px;
}

table.header td.center {
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
}
img.logo {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
/*End Table Logo Code*/
/*End Theme Style Code*/
```

Comment: Your "social" menu is invalid HTML...`ul` can only have `li` as children. Also your main menu has no opening `ul`.

Comment: Also you have a div opening before the `body`...its a bit of a mess really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/ywLa5yg1/1/)

I mostly fixed your code as it was a mess.

The solution I used to center the list was:

```
display: table;
```

That should fix your problems.

Comment: where should that display: table; go?

Comment: In the fiddle, there is no style. Is that normal? This is what the end result should look like, just centered https://blackboard.bsu.edu/bbcswebdav/pid-4904235-dt-content-rid-22336343_1/courses/2016SPR_CS110S800_CLAS_29045_OL/index.html

Comment: Within that Fiddle, I do not see display set to table for any of the menus or submenus @Chris G

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it there. The first ul you have, change it with <ul style="display: table;">. Updated the fiddle :)

Comment: css is applying now, the list is still not centered correctly, even after adding that attribute to the first <ul> tag.

Comment: Can you give a link to your website? Something else must be wrong